# Cannot use mic when using page 2nd time

Tags: c#, xna

In one of my pages in my app, I record via microphone.
As long as I stay on that page, I can stop and re-record.

But when I navigate out of the page and return, and press record, the mic won't catch anything. The result is a mute sound.

Here is the constructor

```
private byte[] _buffer;
private int _passedSecs = 0;

private const string RECORDFILE = "newrecording.wav";

private Microphone _mic = Microphone.Default;
private MemoryStream _stream = new MemoryStream();
private DispatcherTimer _framework;

public MyPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    _framework = new DispatcherTimer();
    _framework.Interval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(33);
    _framework.Tick += _framework_Tick;

    _mic.BufferReady += _mic_BufferReady;
}

private void _mic_BufferReady(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    _mic.GetData(_buffer);
    _stream.Write(_buffer, 0, _buffer.Length);

    var isoStore = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();
    var targetFile = isoStore.CreateFile(RECORDFILE);

    WavHeaderWriter.WriteHeader(targetFile, (int)_stream.Length, 1, _mic.SampleRate);
    var dataBuffer = _stream.GetBuffer();

    targetFile.Write(dataBuffer, 0, (int)_stream.Length);
    targetFile.Flush();
    targetFile.Close();
}
```

Here I record

```
private async void startRecording()
{
    _framework.Start();

    _mic.BufferDuration = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(500);
    _buffer = new byte[_mic.GetSampleSizeInBytes(_mic.BufferDuration)];

    _stream.SetLength(0);
    _mic.Start();
}
```

and here I stop

```
private void stopRecording()
{
    var isoStore = System.IO.IsolatedStorage.IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();
    IsolatedStorageFileStream _data = isoStore.OpenFile(RECORDFILE, FileMode.Open);

    SoundEffect sound = SoundEffect.FromStream(_data);
    _data.Close();
    sound.Play();

    _mic.Stop();
    _framework.Stop();
    isoStore.Dispose();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should unsubscribe the `Microphone event` on `PageNavigatedFrom` event (the event fired when you're navigating from the page)